# How to use apache logs to check complete file downloads

Tags: php, apache2, ubuntu-server

I have a file hosting site that's using this script [MFHS](https://yabsoft.com/mfhs-feature.php).

I want to develop a point system of my own in which points will be rewarded only if the visitor downloaded the whole file.

How can I track it and where are the logs relating to it saved in apache? I am using Ubuntu server.

Or else is there any easier way? The average file sizes on my server is 300mb max file size is 3gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add %X to you log config - see [mod_log_config](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html) for interpreting the values.

Comment: Can you please tell me which file is it, I need to add this code? and can I place that log file in web directory?

Comment: No - I don't know where your Apache installation lives nor how the configuration files have been set up. Look for a file containing uncommented CustomLog and LogFormat drectives.