# Apache Custom Log Format to track complete file downloads

Tags: php, logging, apache2, ubuntu-server

I am trying to write a reward system wherein users will be given reward points if they download complete files, So what should be my log format.

After searching alot this is what I understand its my first time and havent done custom logs before.

First of all **which file should I edit** for custom logs because this thing I cant find. I am using ubuntu server with default apache, php5 and mysql installation

```
# I use this commands and they work fine  
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I think this is what I need to do for my purpose

```
LogLevel notice
LogFormat "%f %u %x %o" rewards
CustomLog /var/www/logs/rewards_log rewards
```

This is as it is command or there is something missing? and is there any particular location where I need to add this?

and one more thing `%o` is for filesize that was sent and is it possible to log only files from a particular directory? or for files with size more than 10mb.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and you should probably be able to find the log directives such as `LogLevel` and others. Note that those settings are global for your whole Apache installation.

The `CustomLog` directive can only be set per server/virtual host basis (see *scope* [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog)).

To use the `CustomLog` directive you must also load the `mod_log` module for apache. This can be done with the `a2enmod` command.

Regards,
Jens

Comment: Any guide to help me how to load a module?   
and is there a way to log only for files with size more than 10mb?

Comment: I run command `a2enmod` It gave me choices but `mod_log` was not available in them, then I checked apache.conf it had already some codes that were for CustomLog. I have added the above code to apache.conf restarted it a file got created but nothing was logged.

Answer (score 0):

Deja vu:

[How to use apache logs to check complete file downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371289/how-to-use-apache-logs-to-check-complete-file-downloads)

Check manual for mod_log_config: case **is** important - that should be %X and %O not %x and %o. %u will only work if you are using basic http authentication (which is a very bad idea) drop a cookie with the (optionally encrypted) username and read it back with %C in your log file if you must take this approach.

A better soluton would be to wrap the file access in a PHP script.

Comment: I want apache logs because of filesizes, most files are above 300mb which I believe using this method will consume more resources. Can you please help me with the Log format? I pasted it as it in apache2.conf a file get created with the name but nothing is getting logged. Also is it possible to log only for files above 10mb? and Yes I change the format to %X and %O